# wget doesn't match patterns with wildcards

Tags: linux, wget

I'm trying to download certain url's which I would like to match with the next pattern using wildcards:

```
http://example.org/subtitles?q=NUMBER_en&format=srt
```

where NUMBER = [0-9]*

the output of that is http 404.

Only works when I run it of the following way:

```
http://example.org/subtitles?q=NUMBER_en&format=srt
```

where NUMBER is an id_number.

I don't want something like `...for i in {0..1000};do wget ....$i...; done`

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
wget http://example.org/subtitles?q={1..100}_en&format=srt
```

The shell will expand to the correct commands and get your files, from 1 to 100.